# Android Studio heap dump is empty

Tags: android-studio, heap-dump

Android Studio 4.0.2 is exporting empty hprof files from memory that is not empty. [image: Empty memory] The profiler shows memory correctly, but I would like to use MAT to analyze the heap because Android Studio does not give the information in an easy to parse way. [image: Non empty memory]

Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: I've noticed empty heap dumps when profiling with emulator which is on edge running out of ram / storage. Wiping emulator and restarting the profiling usually helps. I assume bumping ram / storage in emulator settings could help.

Answer (score 2):

I know this is an older post, but have you tried using ADB to collect the dumpheap of your application?

> adb shell ps | grep `app-name`
>
> adb shell am dumpheap `pid` /data/local/tmp/android.hprof
>
> adb pull /data/local/tmp/android.hprof

You will then need to use the HPROF-Converter to view in Android Studio
https://stuff.mit.edu/afs/sipb/project/android/docs/tools/help/hprof-conv.html